# C# Get script generated HTML from web-page

Tags: c#, download

In the past I have downloaded (html) content from a web-page using a WebRequest (GetResponse) and this have worked fine. However the web-page I need to get this content from have begun using JS, so now in stead of the content I need, I in stead gets the source that generates the content I need.

To get this to work, I began using a WebBrowser component. It works, but it ain't pretty, and since I use a component it has to run in the main-thread:

```
       string content = String.Empty;

        WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser();
        try
        {
            wb.Navigate(new Uri(url));
            while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(5);
            }

            content = wb.DocumentText;
        }
        finally
        {
            wb.Dispose();
        }

        return content;
```

Any suggestions to do this without a WebBrowser component?

Comment: If you really need to execute the javascript to get the data you need, you don't have many choices, and WebBrowser is probably as good as anything. If you are trying to get the data that is being manipulated and rendered by the javascript, you might want to look at what the javascript is doing and try to replicate. For example, is it querying against a web service to get its data? You may be able to directly query the same web service.

Comment: @Jonathan scanning/parsing the javascript is not an option in this case. I was just hoping there would be another option than using the WebBrowser component, as it has to run in the main-thread.